# Pushing \qed to the right within a displayed formula

Tags: math-mode, theorems

In my own custom theorem environment, I'm using the `\qed` command to create a white box. This works wonderfully when the theorem ends with a regular paragraph -- the box is pushed to the right where it should be.

Note that I just type out the `\qed` manually whenever I need it. It works fine. I don't need it automated.

However, if I use this command when the theorem ends with displayed mathmode, the box is just put there right beside the formula -- it is not pushed to the right. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it simpler (as you seem to want, from a comment of yours in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66193). If none of the answers below are what you're looking for, you should really give us the code you are using for your theorems, as it's difficult to answer in the dark like that.

Comment: Related Question for similar issue in text mode: [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If the QED symbol (or tombstone) is needed only rarely, I suggest to use the `\qedhere` feature provided by `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text\qed
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
\[
\pushQED{\qed} 
a=b\qedhere
\popQED
\]     
\end{thm}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the `pushQED`/`popQED` commands do?

Comment: @blinry `amsthm` implements a stack for nesting proofs, possibly with different commands (usually `\qed`), so it's best to comply.

Comment: Why does this not work if pushQED and popQED are removed? is there a way to do it without push and pop?

Comment: Additionally, does this require being inside the theorem environment? And thanks a lot for the helpful answer.

Comment: @6005 No, it doesn't require being in theorem

Answer (score 26):

For the qed symbol to appear flushed right in the last line of aligned equations, I use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand{\j}{\ensuremath{\text{j}}}
\newcommand{\qed}{\tag*{$\blacksquare$}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \left(z_1\cdot z_2\right)^*
            &=\left(\left(a_1+\j b_1\right)\cdot \left(a_2+\j b_2\right)\right)^* \\
            &=\left(\left(a_1a_2-b_1b_2\right)+\j\left(a_1b_2+a_2b_1\right)\right)^* \\
            &=\left(a_1a_2-b_1b_2\right)-\j\left(a_1b_2+a_2b_1\right) \\
            &=a_1a_2-b_1b_2-\j a_1b_2-\j a_2b_1 \\
            &=a_1a_2-a_1\j b_2-a_2\j b_1+\left(-\j\right)^2b_1b_2 \\
            &=\left(a_1-\j b_1\right)\cdot\left(a_2-\j b_2\right) \\
            &=\left(a_1+\j b_1\right)^*\cdot\left(a_2+\j b_2\right)^* \\
            &=z_1^*\cdot z_2^*
            \qed
    \end{align*}            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've been reading quite often, but this is the first time I felt I could actually contribute.

Comment: Amazing. That did for me.

Comment: @Douba Maybe it is better to use `\mathrm{j}` instead of `\text{j}`.

Comment: @L.F. You may be right, thank you for the suggestion. I do not usually use `\mathrm`, because it explicitly requests a roman font. I prefer being able to switch the looks of a document in a centralized way and only mark up semantics elsewhere. However, I see that `\text` falls back to the surrounding font, which may not be what I expect either.

Comment: Used with the `proof` environment, this method places `\qed` symbol twice. To avoid this, I add the command `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` and `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` right before `\end{proof}`.

Comment: @mathreader Or just change ```\qed``` in the example to ```\qedhere```

Answer (score 13):

Not sure with LaTeX, haven't worked with it for a long time, but in Plain, I would use `\eqno`.

```
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1 \over n^2} = {\pi^2 \over 6} \eqno\qed$$
```

Comment: This worked for me after other options not working!

Comment: @Palec; For LaTeX, I am using \tag{\qed} to get the same result.....

Answer (score 8):

You should consider using the [ntheorem](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package which does this kind of thing from the start. But if you really need to use your custom theorem environments, you can take inspiration from what [amsthm](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) does. By stripping the code of everything which is not necessary, you would get:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\providecommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode
    \eqno \def\@badmath{$$}%$$
    \let\eqno\relax \let\leqno\relax \let\veqno\relax
    \hbox{\openbox}%
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\openbox}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1] \qed
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1]
\[
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \qed
\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Of course, in some situations, you might have problems, so for a more robust way of doing it, you should copy/paste the [amsthm](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\@xp\expandafter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
  \fi
}
\let\QED@stack\@empty
\let\qed@elt\relax
\newcommand{\pushQED}[1]{%
  \toks@{\qed@elt{#1}}\@temptokena\expandafter{\QED@stack}%
  \xdef\QED@stack{\the\toks@\the\@temptokena}%
}
\newcommand{\popQED}{%
  \begingroup\let\qed@elt\popQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax\endgroup
}
\def\popQED@elt#1#2\relax{#1\gdef\QED@stack{#2}}
\newcommand{\qedhere}{%
  \begingroup \let\mathqed\math@qedhere
    \let\qed@elt\setQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax \endgroup
}
\newif\ifmeasuring@
\newif\iffirstchoice@ \firstchoice@true
\def\setQED@elt#1#2\relax{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else \iffirstchoice@ \gdef\QED@stack{\qed@elt{}#2}\fi
  \fi
  #1%
}
\def\qed@warning{%
  \PackageWarning{amsthm}{The \@nx\qedhere command may not work
    correctly here}%
}
\newcommand{\mathqed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}
\def\linebox@qed{\hfil\hbox{\qedsymbol}\hfilneg}
\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
  \def\math@qedhere{%
    \@ifundefined{\@currenvir @qed}{%
      \qed@warning\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
    }{%
      \@xp\aftergroup\csname\@currenvir @qed\endcsname
    }%
  }
  \def\displaymath@qed{%
    \relax
    \ifmmode
      \ifinner \aftergroup\linebox@qed
      \else
        \eqno
        \let\eqno\relax \let\leqno\relax \let\veqno\relax
        \hbox{\qedsymbol}%
      \fi
    \else
       \aftergroup\linebox@qed
    \fi
  }
  \@xp\let\csname equation*@qed\endcsname\displaymath@qed
  \def\equation@qed{%
    \iftagsleft@
      \hbox{\phantom{\quad\qedsymbol}}%
      \gdef\alt@tag{%
        \rlap{\hbox to\displaywidth{\hfil\qedsymbol}}%
        \global\let\alt@tag\@empty
      }%
    \else
      \gdef\alt@tag{%
        \global\let\alt@tag\@empty
        \vtop{\ialign{\hfil####\cr
                \tagform@\theequation\cr
                \qedsymbol\cr}}%
        \setbox\z@
      }%
    \fi
  }
  \def\qed@tag{%
    \global\tag@true \nonumber
    &\omit\setboxz@h {\strut@ \qedsymbol}\tagsleft@false
    \place@tag@gather
    \kern-\tabskip
    \ifst@rred \else \global\@eqnswtrue \fi \global\advance\row@\@ne \cr
  }
  \def\split@qed{%
    \def\endsplit{\crcr\egroup \egroup \ctagsplit@false \rendsplit@
      \aftergroup\align@qed
    }%
  }
  \def\align@qed{%
    \ifmeasuring@ \tag*{\qedsymbol}%
    \else \let\math@cr@@@\qed@tag
    \fi
  }
  \@xp\let\csname align*@qed\endcsname\align@qed
  \@xp\let\csname gather*@qed\endcsname\align@qed
%% Needs some patching up for amsmath 1.2
}{% end of amsmath branch, start plain LaTeX branch
  \def\math@qedhere{%
    \@ifundefined{\@currenvir @qed}{%
      \qed@warning \aftergroup\displaymath@qed
    }{%
      \@xp\aftergroup\csname\@currenvir @qed\endcsname
    }%
  }
  \def\displaymath@qed{%
    \relax
    \ifmmode
      \ifinner \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\linebox@qed
      \else
        \eqno \def\@badmath{$$}%
        \let\eqno\relax \let\leqno\relax \let\veqno\relax
        \hbox{\qedsymbol}%
      \fi
    \else
       \aftergroup\linebox@qed
    \fi
  }
  \@ifundefined{ver@leqno.clo}{%
    \def\equation@qed{\displaymath@qed \quad}%
  }{%
    \def\equation@qed{\displaymath@qed}%
  }
  \def\@tempa#1$#2#3\@nil{%
    \def\[{#1$#2\def\@currenvir{displaymath}#3}%
  }%
  \expandafter\@tempa\[\@nil
}
\@ifpackageloaded{amstex}{%
  \def\@tempa{TT}%
}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
    \def\@tempb#1 v#2.#3\@nil{#2}%
    \ifnum\@xp\@xp\@xp\@tempb\csname ver@amsmath.sty\endcsname v0.0\@nil
       <\tw@
      \def\@tempa{TT}%
    \else
      \def\@tempa{TF}%
    \fi
  }{%
    \def\@tempa{TF}
  }%
}
\if\@tempa
  \renewcommand{\math@qedhere}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}%
\fi
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsquare}{%
  \begingroup \usefont{U}{msa}{m}{n}\thr@@\endgroup
}
\providecommand{\qedsymbol}{\openbox}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\preto{\theorem}{\pushQED{\qed}}
\preto{\endtheorem}{\popQED}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1] \qedhere
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1]
\[
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \qedhere
\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

A few comments on the code: the big chunk is just a copy/paste of the file amsthm.sty. If you decide to use this package, you won't need it anymore. The important point is to modify the `{theorem}` environment by adding `\pushQED{\qed}` before it starts and `\popQED` before it ends. For this, I've used the `\preto` command from the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Answer (score 7):

You can insert the display equation in text mode with a forced `\displaystyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1] \qed
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1]
\[
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \qed
\]
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[1]\par
\vspace{\abovedisplayshortskip}
\hfill $\displaystyle f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ \qed
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Since the last line of the preceding paragraph and "short", I've inserted a skip of `\abovedisplayshortskip`. A "long" paragraph ending should use `\abovedisplayskip`.

Comment: This works. However, there is a problem with "abovedisplayshortskip" because it only works with your particular example, in which the last line of the previous paragraph is short enough. However, the skip should be larger if this line is a bit longer. Can you adjust this so that it works for all situations?

Comment: @MayGodBlessKnuth: As I mentioned at the end of my post, you should use `\abovedisplayskip` for a longer paragraph. I'll see what can be done to automate this requirement.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I must have missed that. But is there no way to combine both into one solution to make it automatic?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\displaymath@qed` from the `amsthm` package. Due to the `@` in the name you'll need a wrapper macro. In the code below I "overload" `\qed` in such a way that it acts as `\displaymath@qed` in math mode and as the standard `\qed` in text mode.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\let\saveqed\qed
\renewcommand\qed{%
   \ifmmode\displaymath@qed
   \else\saveqed
   \fi}
\begin{document}
text
\[
  a=b\makeatletter\displaymath@qed
\]
more text \qed
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `\makeatletter\displaymath@qed` inside the document be just `\qed`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a much easier work around. Hopefully this helps anyone else who stumbles across this question:

```
\begin{align}
&E^2 + \frac{1}{4}(-2E^2 +2B^2)\\
 &= 1/2 (E^2 +B^2)\\
 &= \mathlarger{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}
\end{align}

\begin{flushright}
\qedsymbol
\end{flushright}
```

Comment: The question is how to insert the QED symbol within a formula (and not afterwards). In case of an unfavorable page break formula and QED could be separated here.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. What I read was "..if I use this command when the theorem ends with displayed mathmode, the box is just put there right beside the formula -- it is not pushed to the right. How can I accomplish that?" 
I feel as though I did help answer that, though I suppose you feel there are better and more nuanced replies. That's fair.

Answer (score 0):

A hack I can use even in mathjax when I take notes in typora is to set the equation number to the qed symbol. Example:

```
\begin{align}
k_m(x,y) =& \sum_{\substack{h, h'}} k((x,h), (y, h'))p(h|x)p(h'|y)\\
=&  \sum_{\substack{h, h'}} k((y,h), (x,h')) p(h'|x)p(h|y) \\
=& k_m(y, x) \tag*{$\blacksquare$} \\
\end{align}
```

[image]

Caveat:
If you ever reference this equation, you will have that symbol instead of an equation number. But you can of course just reference the line before that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat.