# Qed right justified at the end of the last line of cases in display style

Tags: cases

I'm trying to get a qed symbol at the right end of the last line of a cases environment, but when I try e.g.

```
\hfill$\displaystyle\begin{cases}a&b\\c&d\\e&f\end{cases}$ \qed
```

the symbol is centered. How do I get it still on the right side of the page but aligned with the last line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing \qed to the right within a displayed formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/pushing-qed-to-the-right-within-a-displayed-formula)

Comment: The linked question doesn't move the qed box to the last line of a `cases` statement.  Please provide a small compilable example, so that we can see (1) what document class you're using, (2) whether this display is at the end of a proof, and (3) if in a proof, what theorem package you're using.

Comment: @barbara I'll have to do this in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a proper displayed equation if it is supposed to take the whole line!

Next, I'd use the `{numcases}` environment (cases.sty) along with `\notag` and `\tag*`.

But that makes me discover `\tag*` is not supported in `{numcases}`. Oops, sorry.

So from the beginning: Wait a few days for the updated cases.sty to propagate on CTAN, and download it or let it automatically update. Then, in your document head declare

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
```

and in the body, use

```
\begin{numcases}{x =}
a& b \notag \\
c& d \notag \\
e& f \tag*{\Box}
\end{numcases}
```

Comment: I do some of my editing on an android phone with verbtex. I'm worried the app won't pull the updated package.

Comment: If your TeX installation is hard to update, you can download the file from CTAN using a browser, and save it in the directory with your document.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It's a little confusing though that the numcases has to not be in displaymath, the left side is in math mode, and the right side is not.

Comment: Because it includes equation numbering, it has to be the whole display-math environment, like {eqnarray} or {align}, but distinct from {cases} or {aligned}. The far right "explanations" are in text mode following the original `\cases` from plain TeX (cases.sty predates amsmath), and the amsmath documentation recommends putting the entries inside `\text{ }`, but the difference/incompatability is indeed a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `witharrows`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{DispWithArrows*}<x =>
a& b  \\
c& d  \\
e& f \tag*{$\Box$}
\end{DispWithArrows*}

\end{document}
```