# Tcolorbox : create a proof environnement with a QED symbol at the very end

Tags: tcolorbox

I have created a tcolorbox environment to write proofs.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcolorbox{proof}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  top=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,frame empty,
  borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue},
  coltitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  title=Proof
}

\begin{proof}
  Let's show that girls are Evil.
  \begin{adjustwidth}{5mm}{0mm}
    Girls require time and money
    \begin{equation}
      girls = time \times money 
    \end{equation}
    Time is money
    \begin{equation}
      time = money 
    \end{equation}
    So girls are money squared:
    \begin{equation}
      girls = money^2 
    \end{equation}
    Money is the root of all evil
    \begin{equation}
      money = \sqrt{evil}
    \end{equation}
    So, girls are evil:
    \begin{equation}
      girls = \left(\sqrt{evil}\right)^2 = evil
    \end{equation}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  We have shown that girls are Evil.
\end{proof}
% From https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/funny-math-proofs.html
```

Now, I would like that a *blue* square is automatically added at the end of the proof (at the very end of the last line) like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/pushing-qed-to-the-right-within-a-displayed-formula). I do not know how to specify this in the proof environment definition.

Comment: Try the examples given in [doc of `tcolorbox` v4.42](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), sec. 17.4 Using other theorem environments with tcolorbox.

Comment: I think adding the `after upper={\qed}` option to `\newtcolorbox` with the `\usepackage{amsthm}` package will do what you want. I would also suggest you _not_ use the name `proof` as your envuronment name.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Maybe wrap the words with `\text`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `ntheorem` package,  you have the automatic placement of the end-of-proof symbol at the end of the last line, including the cases when the last line is an equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier} 
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\theoremstyle{nonumberbreakn}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape\color{blue}}
\theoremseparator{:\smallskip}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\color{blue}\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  top=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,frame empty,
  borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue},
  coltitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  sharp corners
}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  Let's show that girls are Evil.
  \begin{adjustwidth}{5mm}{0mm}
    Girls require time and money
    \begin{equation}
      girls = time \times money
    \end{equation}
    Time is money
    \begin{equation}
      time = money
    \end{equation}
    So girls are money squared:
    \begin{equation}
      girls = money^2
    \end{equation}
    Money is the root of all evil
    \begin{equation}
      money = \sqrt{evil}
    \end{equation}
    So, girls are evil:
    \begin{equation*}
      girls = \left(\sqrt{evil}\right)^2 = evil
    \end{equation*}
  \end{adjustwidth}
% We have shown that girls are Evil.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In the code given in my first message, I have chosen to have a line break after the "proof" label. To keep this line break using your code, one has to use the `nonumberbreak` theoremstyle in place of  `nonumberplain`.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the exact layout. I'll fix that in a moment.

Answer (score 7):

Add the lines

```
\usepackage{amssymb}% defines \blacksquare
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\null\hfill\textcolor{blue}{$\blacksquare$}}
```

to your preamble; replace `\blacksquare` by `\square` if the symbol is too massive.

For LaTeX versions older than 2020/10/01, you need the `etoolbox` package before using `\AtEndEnvironment`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\null\hfill\textcolor{blue}{$\blacksquare$}}%
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcolorbox{proof}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  top=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,frame empty,
  borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue},
  coltitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  title=Proof
}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Let's show that girls are Evil.
  \begin{adjustwidth}{5mm}{0mm}
    So, girls are evil:
    \begin{equation}
      girls = \left(\sqrt{evil}\right)^2 = evil
    \end{equation}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  We have shown that girls are Evil.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34020/110998)

Comment: Thanks. However, when I compile your code, I got the error `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \AtEndEnvironment
l.3 \AtEndEnvironment`

Comment: @J.Martin `\AtEndEnvironment` is provided by `etoolbox` package.

Comment: With a recent version of LaTeX, the `\AtEndEnvironment` command is already builtin.