# ntheorem: Manually placing end-of-proof symbol in an equation

Tags: theorems, ntheorem, newtheorem

I would like to use `ntheorem` to produce theorems and proofs.  I've got an end-of-proof symbol that works ok but, in the case of a trivial result, I'd like to place the symbol in the theorem itself.  I've got something that works ok, except when the theorem ends with an equation.

I'm not 100% sure that I'm using the package correctly.  The following is my attempt at a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof:}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Some theorems need a proof.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
And the end of proof symbol works even with an equation such as
\[
P = NP.
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{thm}
Some are trivial and don't need a proof. \hfill\proofSymbol
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
But how do you place the symbol when the trivial result ends with an equation
\[
x^{2}-1 = (x-1)(x+1)? \hfill\proofSymbol
\]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of this code]

Any corrections to what I've done?  And, most importantly, how do I place the end-of-proof symbol correcly in Theorem 3?

Comment: [Pushing \qed to the right within a displayed formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66152/134144) seems to be closely related (duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `trivthm` environment, which shares the counter of `thm`, and declare `\theoremsymbol` just before this environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{trivthm}[thm]{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof:}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Some theorems need a proof.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
And the end of proof symbol works even with an equation such as
\[
P = NP.
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{trivthm}
Some are trivial and don't need a proof.
\end{trivthm}

\begin{trivthm}
But how do you place the symbol when the trivial result ends with an equation
\[
x^{2}-1 = (x-1)(x+1)?
\]
\end{trivthm}

\end{document}
```

[image]